# Log stream does not pick up messages

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.0

In ASP.NET Core application I added the following to the controller action

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Wrote log at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("Wrote error log at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Wrote info log at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
```

I enabled `Application Logging (Filesystem)` under `Diagnostic Logs` menu in Azure, but under `Log Stream` I do not see any of my trace messages. Am I missing something?

**Update**

I created a sample MVC application using the .NET Framework (instead of .NET Core) and `Log Stream` works fine when I use `System.Diagnostics.Trace` to output messages.

Does this mean I cannot use `System.Diagnostics.Trace` in .NET Core to output messages to `Log Stream`? This works in Visual Studio to output messages to Output window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [Logging in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.1#azure-log-streaming)

> Navigate to the **Log Streaming** page to view application messages. They're logged by application through the `ILogger` interface.

In the ASP.NET Core app I injected the logger in the Controller:

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

And now can use it in Controller actions.

```
_logger.LogWarning(100, "Warning using ILogger");
```

And now these logs show up on **Log Streaming** page in Azure web app.